# Momentum uncertainty in Uncertainty principle

Tags: operators, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, statistics

In my physics textbook, to estimate atomic and nuclear energies, they used the Uncertainty principle. In this problem, $\Delta p=p-(-p)=2p.$ But in many different problems, people just defined the $\Delta p=p.$ What is right?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll add this answer more as a long comment. Personally I find it more helpful to go back to definitions. In this case the uncertainty relation says $\sigma_x\sigma_p \geq \hbar/2$. In the notation of your problem $\Delta x^2 = \sigma_x^2 = \langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x \rangle^2$ and $\Delta p^2 = \langle p^2 \rangle - \langle p \rangle^2$ where the $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the expectation value of an operator. Supposedly the problem is symmetric to reflection about the origin, so $\langle p \rangle = 0$ and $\langle x \rangle = 0$ leaving you with $\Delta x^2 \Delta p^2 = \langle x^2 \rangle \langle p^2 \rangle \geq (\hbar/2)^2$. Now the kinetic energy can be expressed as $K = p^2/2m$. Using $\langle K \rangle = \langle p^2 \rangle/2m$ you are finally left with $\langle K \rangle \geq (\hbar / 2 \Delta x)^2$ which is the answer from your problem and you can substitute e.g. $\Delta x \approx 0.1~\text{nm}$ or $0.1~\text{fm}$ to get the numerical results.

Caveat: the uncertainty relation in your textbook is defined as $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar$ whereas I used $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar/2$ which is indeed the correct formula provided $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ stand for standard deviations of the position and momentum. (You can check this in a textbook e.g. D.J. Griffiths's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics or compare it to the infinite wisdom of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle).) I suspect that in your problem this factor of $2$ is reintroduced via this trickery with $\Delta p = 2 p$. Nevertheless, it is really only a rough approximation as the other answer points it out, so these factors really don't matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

The Uncertainty Principle is being used to get a very rough approximation of the energies involved in chemical and nuclear interactions. Given an uncertainty of position $\Delta x$, there is a limit $\Delta p$ to how well you can know the momentum. If you interact with an atom or nucleus, you don't know what momentum you might get, but you know it will often be $\Delta p$ or bigger. This is because if you measure a value $\Delta p/10$, you know it comes with an uncertainty of $\Delta p$.

So the value you get isn't anything better than a way to say a measured $p$ might be around this big. Saying the that the value you might measure is $\Delta p$ or $\Delta p/2$ are just different ways of getting this rough approximation. Neither one is really accurate, but both are good order-of-magnitude guesses.